# table inside a scrollable div -> div does not overflow if columns are to big

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside a div with overflow: auto. 
If I set the column width to high the browser shrinks them and the div does not overflow.

In my project I have to set the widths using jQuery().width() but it also doesn't work without any js.

Does the table only overflow I the content is too large?
How can I get the columns to for example be 250px so that the div overflows?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">

            <div id="tableWrapper">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 250px">100.00</td>
                            <td style="width: 250px">100.00</td>
                            <td style="width: 250px">100.00</td>
                            <td style="width: 250px">100.00</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tableWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is a example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfk7sxuy/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want fixed width columns (250px) you can use the `table-layout: fixed;` property:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
    width: 250px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wfk7sxuy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `min-width` of the cells to the width that you need.

```
#tableWrapper td { min-width: 250px; }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wfk7sxuy/3/